# Does any wysiwyg editor can display an image provided by an URL?

Tags: angular, image, wysiwyg

I want to display some images into a wysiwyg editor but i don't want to upload them. I want to put an external URL and then the wysiwyg editor to display it into an iframe or something like that. Does anyone know a rich text editor who can do that?

I'm using ngx-wig and he can't do what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have looked into that npm package and it does support images url's, but it's tricky since there is no button to do so on the editor, but since it's a wysiwyg editor you can edit the [content] variable of your editor and add the

You can look into this stackblitz where I add an image to display on the editor : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-wig-img-test

Now you gonna need to add your own button that will take in an Url and add to the content of your editor the img tag

Comment: @yougeen yes sorry I made it private for some reason... you can check it now

Comment: it will work after i'll add the button to add the content. thx!